# ASP.NET MVC 2/3 validation attributes - if one triggers as false, are the others short-circuited?

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, file-handling

A follow-up to my question here: [ASP.NET MVC 2 - Handling files in an edit action; Or, is it possible to create an 'Optional' data annotation which would skip over other attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7212053/399584)

If a validation attribute triggers as false (say, a `Required` field is missing), will other validation attributes also be invoked, or will they be skipped over/short-circuited?

I ask because I have a custom file validation attribute I'd like to apply only if a file actually exists.  I'm using Simon Ince's conditional validation to toggle `Required` fields based on whether or not I'm creating or editing an entity, but I'm not sure if it's possible to actually apply another attribute based on the result of the first.  I mean, the following file validator would likely throw an exception if the file didn't exist:

```
public class ValidateFileAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;

        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string[] validExtensions = { "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png" };
        string[] validMimeTypes = { "image/jpeg", "image/pjepeg", "image/gif", "image/png" };

        string[] potentialFileExtensions = file.FileName.Split('.');
        string lastExtension = potentialFileExtensions[(potentialFileExtensions.Length - 1)];
        string mimeType = file.ContentType;

        bool extensionFlag = false;
        bool mimeFlag = false;

        foreach (string extension in validExtensions)
        {
            if (extension == lastExtension)
            {
                extensionFlag = true;
            }
        }

        foreach (string mt in validMimeTypes)
        {
            if (mt == mimeType)
            {
                mimeFlag = true;
            }
        }

        if (extensionFlag && mimeFlag)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to approach the problem.  The files may or may not be there, but if they are I want to validate them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to get re-use out of your custom attribute you may just be complicating things trying to place the logic in a custom attribute. Can you run your logic in the controller action (or in a separate library that it calls?) This way you don't have to deal with trying to chain attributes.